# what is the right time complexity of this function

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I'm a beginner in data structure and algorithms. I have come across this problem in a book (*Data Structures And Algorithms Made Easy In Java*) and the complexity is given as O(√n) in the book. To my understanding, it looks the function grows more than O(√n) but less than O(n) with the input.

```
public void function (int n) {
   int i=1, s=1;
   // s is increasing not at rate 1 but i
   while( s <= n) {
      i++;
      s= s+i;
      System.out.println(“*");
   }
}
```

Can you please explain what is the correct time complexity of this function?

Comment: In each iteration `s = i*(i+1)/2` and i is the number of iterations, so O(sqrt(n)) is correct.

Comment: @Henry, go ahead and post the answer.  Like the placeholder of this comment box says "Avoid answering questions in comments".

Answer (score 2):

The book is correct. Each time, `one` is added to `i` and `i` is added to `s`. Hence, `s` will be `1` and `1 + 2`, `1 + 2‌ + 3`, ..., `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + k`. Now, `k` is the number of running loop and the complexity is `Theta(k)` or `O(k)`. Now to find the value of `k`, we need to solve `1 + 2 + ... + k = n`. As `1 + 2 + ... + k = k(k+1)/2`, we will have `k*(k+1)/2 = n`. Hence, `k = Theta(sqrt(n))` (just solve the equation), and it means the algorithm is in `O(sqrt(n))`.